# Public Knowledge base: Attempt to de-reference a null object

Tags: visualforce, sandbox

We're having some issues with the public knowledge base in our sandbox site that is starting to cause some major headaches.
Up untill a couple of weeks ago the site was working fine, however we are now getting an error message that says :

> "Authorization Required. You must first log in or register before
>   accessing this page".

I've had an email to tell me that the issue is in the `pkb_controller` on line 323. The email says that this is the issue: 
caused by:

> System.NullPointerException: Attempt to de-reference a null object
>   Class.pkb_Controller.__sfdc_viewingArticle: line 323, column 1

The line is:

```
public Boolean viewingArticle { get { return (!isBlank(theArticle.Id)); } }
```

No one has made any changes to this file and no changes have been made to the article set up. We have reset our sandbox and reinstalled public knowledge base, but the error is exactly the same. I'm not experienced enough with visualforce to know what this error means or how it would be fixed, so any help would be massivley appreciated.

Comment: Where is the class called from, page or component?

Comment: The `theArticle` field is null; check the code that sets that field.

Comment: You probably need to perform a Null pointer check on line 323, column 1.
If there is an "If statement" you can perform the Null pointer check by just doing something like, "if(field__c!=null && field__c>0)" , that kind of check. Will be better if you can show us the code as Rahul is asking :)

Comment: Hence I always use a get;set; property and assign values in constructor. Getter sometimes gives issues woth order of execution, especially when used in visualforce components.

Comment: `public Boolean viewingArticle { 
       get {return (theArticle == null ? false : !isBlank(theArticle.Id)); } 
    }`  will resolve the NPE; root cause is why `theArticle` is null. Getter order is undefined in VF controller and Spring 17 may have changed this for you